# Extra fields on intermediate table for Peewee ManyToMany relation

Tags: python-3.x, orm, peewee

I'm trying to set up manytomany relationship through an intermediary table with extra columns in Peewee 3.2.2 like this:

```
ThroughDeferred = DeferredThroughModel()

class Playlist(BaseModel):
    ...
    movies = ManyToManyField(Movie, backref='playlists', through_model=ThroughDeferred)

class Movie(BaseModel):
    name = CharField(max_length=100)

class PlaylistMovie(BaseModel):
    playlist = ForeignKeyField(column_name='playlist_id', field='id', model=Playlist)
    movie = ForeignKeyField(column_name='movie_id', field='id', model=Movie)
    position = PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)

    class Meta:
        table_name = 'playlist_movie_relation'

ThroughDeferred.set_model(PlaylistMovie)
```

But then, upon query all i get is the list of related movie data without the position.

```
list(playlist.movies.dicts()) 
> [{name: 'blah', id: 3}, ...]
```

How can I get the position data within the playlist.movies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ought to work:

```
query = (Movie
         .select(Movie, PlaylistMovie.position)
         .join(PlaylistMovie)
         .where(PlaylistMovie.playlist == playlist)
         .order_by(PlaylistMovie.position))

for movie in query:
    print(movie.name, movie.playlistmovie.position)
```

Comment: So as long as there're extra fields, intermediate tables should better be used via explicit joins rather than through_model declarations, right? By the way, thanks for the fantastic work on peewee.

Comment: That's my opinion, certainly. The many-to-many field really works best for very simplistic relationships. I never use it personally.